# Registry issues while trying to install system-wide Julia application in a singularity container

Tags: julia, singularity-container

I'm trying to build a singularity container able to run a Julia application I've written.

I do this based on an official docker image containing Julia 1.2. Here is my definition file:

```
Bootstrap:docker
From:julia:1.2-buster

%post
    apt-get update -y
    apt-get install -y git
    apt-get install -y wget
    mkdir -p /usr/local/src/git-lfs
    cd /usr/local/src/git-lfs
    wget https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases/download/v2.8.0/git-lfs-linux-amd64-v2.8.0.tar.gz
    tar -xvzf git-lfs-linux-amd64-v2.8.0.tar.gz
    ./install.sh
    cd ..
    git clone https://gitlab.pasteur.fr/bli/qaf_demux.git
    cd qaf_demux/Julia/QafDemux/
    /usr/local/julia/bin/julia --project=. --eval 'import Pkg; Pkg.activate("."), Pkg.instantiate()'
    apt-get remove -y git
    apt-get autoremove -y
    apt-get clean -y

%environment
    export LC_ALL=C
    export PATH=/usr/local/src/qaf_demux/Julia/QafDemux/bin:"${PATH}"

%runscript
    exec /usr/local/src/qaf_demux/Julia/QafDemux/bin/qaf_demux.sh "$@"
```

The build fails during the `%post` phase, when I try to get `julia` to instantiate the project:

```
+ /usr/local/julia/bin/julia --project=. --eval import Pkg; Pkg.activate("."), Pkg.instantiate()
Activating environment at `/usr/local/src/qaf_demux/Julia/QafDemux/Project.toml`
   Cloning default registries into `~/.julia`
   Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
     Added registry `General` to `~/.julia/registries/General`
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
ERROR: Package FASTX [c2308a5c-f048-11e8-3e8a-31650f418d12] not found in a registry.
Stacktrace:
 [1] pkgerror(::String) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.2/Pkg/src/Types.jl:112
 [2] check_registered(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.2/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:924
 [3] up(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}, ::Pkg.Types.UpgradeLevel) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.2/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1043
 [4] #up#43(::Pkg.Types.UpgradeLevel, ::Pkg.Types.PackageMode, ::Bool, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::typeof(Pkg.API.up), ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.2/Pkg/src/API.jl:167
 [5] #up#38 at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [6] #up at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [7] #instantiate#81(::Nothing, ::Bool, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::typeof(Pkg.API.instantiate), ::Pkg.Types.Context) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.2/Pkg/src/API.jl:463
 [8] instantiate at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.2/Pkg/src/API.jl:461 [inlined]
 [9] #instantiate#80 at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.2/Pkg/src/API.jl:458 [inlined]
 [10] instantiate() at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.2/Pkg/src/API.jl:458
```

If I use the same docker image to build a "sandbox" container (`singularity build --sandbox <the folder> docker://julia:1.2-buster`), and working with it via `singularity shell --writable <the folder>`, I can perform this project instanciation step as a normal user, and it seems to work.

If I try it as root, the same `ERROR: Package FASTX [c2308a5c-f048-11e8-3e8a-31650f418d12] not found in a registry.` error occurs.

Same issue if (still as root in that writable sandbox), I try do it in the REPL:

```
(v1.2) pkg> activate .
Activating environment at `/usr/local/src/qaf_demux/Julia/QafDemux/Project.toml`

(QafDemux) pkg> instantiate
  Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
ERROR: Package FASTX [c2308a5c-f048-11e8-3e8a-31650f418d12] not found in a registry.
```

Is it the proper way to install a Julia application system-wide?

(More or less cross-posted at an earlier step of my attempts at https://discourse.julialang.org/t/julia-packages-with-singularity/19883/8, no answer yet)

---

#### Edit (23/09/2019)

Thanks to @[David Varela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7077117/david-varela)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57998222/1878788), using `Pkg.Registry.add(Pkg.RegistrySpec(; url="https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git")); Pkg.Registry.add(Pkg.RegistrySpec(; url="https://github.com/BioJulia/BioJuliaRegistry.git"));` I have now a working definition file:

```
Bootstrap:docker
From:julia:1.2-buster

%post
    apt-get update -y
    apt-get install -y git
    apt-get install -y wget
    apt-get install -y build-essential
    mkdir -p /usr/local/src/git-lfs
    cd /usr/local/src/git-lfs
    wget https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases/download/v2.8.0/git-lfs-linux-amd64-v2.8.0.tar.gz
    tar -xvzf git-lfs-linux-amd64-v2.8.0.tar.gz
    ./install.sh
    cd ..
    git clone https://gitlab.pasteur.fr/bli/qaf_demux.git
    cd qaf_demux/Julia/QafDemux/
    /usr/local/julia/bin/julia --project=. --eval 'import Pkg; Pkg.Registry.add(Pkg.RegistrySpec(; url="https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git")); Pkg.Registry.add(Pkg.RegistrySpec(; url="https://github.com/BioJulia/BioJuliaRegistry.git")); Pkg.activate("."); Pkg.instantiate(); Pkg.build()'
    strip deps/builddir/qaf_demux
    export PATH="/usr/local/julia/bin:${PATH}"
    export PATH=/usr/local/src/qaf_demux/Julia/QafDemux/bin:"${PATH}"
    export PATH=/usr/local/src/qaf_demux/Julia/QafDemux/deps/builddir:"${PATH}"
    which qaf_demux
    qaf_demux --help
    apt-get remove -y git
    apt-get autoremove -y
    apt-get clean -y
    rm -rf /usr/local/src/git-lfs

%environment
    export LC_ALL=C
    export PATH=/usr/local/src/qaf_demux/Julia/QafDemux/deps/builddir:"${PATH}"

%runscript
    exec /usr/local/src/qaf_demux/Julia/QafDemux/deps/builddir/qaf_demux "$@"
```

However, the resulting image needs a kernel too recent for our computing cluster.

I would therefore like to try to build a similar image based on `docker://julia:1.0-stretch`, but the registry manipulation API of `Pkg` [did not exist prior to Julia 1.1](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/api/index.html#Registry-API-Reference-1).

**Is there an alternative 1.0-compatible way to get the missing registries?**

#### Self-answer:

I found out that the registries can be "manually" obtained using git, as follows:

```
mkdir -p /root/.julia/registries
cd /root/.julia/registries
git clone https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git
git clone https://github.com/BioJulia/BioJuliaRegistry.git
```

(In the above, I use root's `.julia` directory, since root is the one to build and install the application.)

To be noted: the instantiating and building of the application can then proceed without a `Manifest.toml` file. I found this out because I tried to remove this file as part of an attempt to remove version constraints on packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is accurate, there is no package with the name `FASTX` that exists in the `General` registry (as of this date).

In your case: you have to run `Pkg.Registry.add(Pkg.RegistrySpec(; url="https://github.com/BioJulia/BioJuliaRegistry.git"))` before you run `Pkg.instantiate()`

In the general case: To `instantiate` a project that depends on unregistered packages, you have to supply the `Manifest.toml` file (there does not seem to be one in the [directory](https://gitlab.pasteur.fr/bli/qaf_demux/tree/master/Julia/QafDemux) you linked).

Comment: This error does seem to be more specific to Julia than singularity

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I understand correctly, when I was running julia in the container as normal user, julia somehow had  access to the host system's julia "installation" for the user, that already included the needed registry. Isn't that defeating the purpose of working within containers?

Comment: How did you find how to add the correct registry? Now I have a `ERROR: Package CodecZlib [944b1d66-785c-5afd-91f1-9de20f533193] not found in a registry.` and I can't find what address to put for the `url` argument of `Pkg.RegistrySpec`

Comment: I added the `Manifest.toml` file to the git repository, but this does not fix the registry issue for `FASTX`. I still have to use the `Pkg.Registry.add` command you suggested. And I still have registry issues for other packages.

Comment: I just googled the package, it has instructions: https://github.com/BioJulia/FASTX.jl. The `CodecZlib` error is suspicious, since it **is** registered in `General`. Did you try explicitly adding `General`?

Comment: Sorry, adding the `Manifest.toml` file seems to solve the issue for `CodecZlib`, but then the error happens for other packages. Currently, `BinaryProvider`.

Comment: Adding the `General` registry seems to solve the `BinaryProvider` issue. (`Pkg.Registry.add(Pkg.RegistrySpec(; url="https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"))`)

Comment: @DavidVarela According to https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/api/index.html#Registry-API-Reference-1 the commands you suggested do not exist in Julia 1.0. How would one proceed to add missing registries back then? I would like to try to build my container based on `docker://julia:1.0-stretch` so that it can run on our computing cluster whose kernel is a bit old.